# Cómo funciona el click sostenido en celular

Tags: javascript

Estoy moviendo una caja con el mouse en la pc pero en el celular no me funciona el arrastre, ya intenté con **ontouchstart** pero no funciona ¿qué hago?

```js
button.onmousedown = function() {
// INSTRUCCIONES      
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar algo de codigo?, asi podremos saber cómo estás utilizando el método, la ejecución no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

intentaste con el método touchmove?.
[en esta guía](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp) habla sobre el funcionamiento que intentas hacer.

- **touchend**, ocurre cuando el usuario retira el dedo de un elemento.
- **touchmove**, ocurre cuando el usuario mueve el dedo por la pantalla.
- **touchcancel**, se produce cuando se interrumpe el toque.

Como puedes observar [esta guía del touchmove](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchmove.asp) dice.
El evento **touchstart** ocurre cuando el usuario toca la pantalla, y tu intentas mover objetos en ella.
Entonces realmente no necesitas el evento ***touchstar***, sino que necesitas el evento **touchmove**.

Puedes llamarlo de diferentes maneras:

```
<button ontouchmove="myFunction(event)"> Mueveme! </button>
```

Directamente en tu Html.

---

```
object.ontouchmove = myScript;
```

Desde tu Javascript.

---

```
object.addEventListener("touchmove", myScript);
```

Desde Javascript, usando el método addEventListener ().

---

Espero y sea de tu ayuda.